# Как построить бинарное дерево по скобочной записи?

Tags: алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Как можно построить бинарное дерево используя, например, следующую скобочную запись:

`( B ( C ) ) A ( D )`

Не пойму, как это сделать

Comment: А что оно должно из себя представлять? Какая задача помимо представления информации в виде бинарного дерева?

Comment: *используя, например, следующую скобочную запись `( B ( C )) A ( D )`* Это вообще не дерево, а фиг знает что. Ни левое, ни правое... Даже если считать, что А - это корень, то опять же пробелы расставлены абы как, не отличить, где левый узел. где правый...

Comment: @Komdosh, простая задача: нужно по скобочной записи сделать прямой, обратный и концевой обходы

Comment: @Akina, поправил описание. Т.е. на пробелы нужно ориентироваться при построении дерева? Не знаю, правильно ли это, потому что задание дали такое. Можно использовать пример такого дерева `(8 (3 (1) (6 (4) (7))) (10 (14 (13))))`

Comment: а) Найти буковку что вне скобок, принять ее за корень: б) взять что стоит слева от корня и принять его левой веткой, повторить для него рекурсивно с п. а; в) то же самое сделать рекурсивно для правой ветки

Comment: Алгоритм Андрея должен сработать для этого примера.

Comment: @SimpleUser, то что вы написали в комментарии — это совсем другая запись, тут нет члена стоящего вне скобок

Comment: @АндрейNOP, т.е. для этих двух случаев нужно будет писать разные алгоритмы построения?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, подскажите, какой алгоритм можно использовать для построения дерева из чисел (написанного выше)?

Comment: *Можно использовать пример такого дерева* Опять какое-то неправильное дерево. У узла 14 узел 13 - левый или правый? а не видно... в правильной, строгой, записи, где левый и правый узлы различаются, узел может быть или такой `N` или такой `N (...) (...)`. Вместо многоточия - или узел, или пробел. Всё, третьего варианта нет. Скобочная запись должна ОДНОЗНАЧНО конвертироваться в дерево (и обратно).

Comment: Правильное дерево могло бы быть, скажем, вот таким: `(8(3(1)(6(4)(7)))(10( )(14(13)( ))))`, или таким: `8(3(1)(6(4)(7)))(10( )(14(13)( )))`. Причём первый вариант - это дерево, являющееся поддеревом какого-то дерева, а второй - это конечное дерево.

Comment: @Akina, пример с числами взял с [сайта](https://markoutte.me/students/binary-search-tree/). Спасибо за разъяснение, уже потихоньку начинаю разбираться с материалом

Comment: Кстати, для освоения рекомендую рассмотреть показанные деревья в любом редакторе, который подсвечивает парную скобку (тот же NPP, скажем). очень наглядно...

Answer (score 0):

Так понимаю, что для чисел указанных в вашем комментарии суть в том, что первый элемент в скобке является подкорнем, далее первая открытая скобка до закрытия является левой ветвью, а вторая скобка правой ветвью.

Таким образом алгоритм получается такой, первую скобку необходимо пропустить (также в конце потребуется пропустить последнюю закрывающую скобку). Далее число сохраняете, считываете следующий символ пока не найдёте открывающуюся или закрывающуюся скобку. Если это первая открывающаяся скобка идёте влево, если закрывающаяся идёте назад, если это вторая открывающаяся скобка, значит нужно идти направо.

Comment: Таким образом можно все дерево пройти? Не совсем понимаю логику.

Comment: Реализация на коленке http://tpcg.io/r5NtiF

Comment: круто, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, кто помогал разобраться в данной теме и поделились идеями и реализациями.

Сделал еще свою реализацию на Паскале) Если есть какие идеи по улучшению - буду очень благодарен.

Я, к сожалению, сразу не предоставил всей необходимо информации. Бинарное дерево задается следующей структурой:

```
< бд > ::= < пусто > | (< бд > < буква >< бд >)
< пусто > ::=
```

***Пример с буквами***

```
type
  PTree = ^Tree;
  Tree = record
    Data: char;
    Left, Right: PTree;
  end;

// Построение бинарного дерева
procedure AddToTree(var aTree: PTree; s: string);
var
  i, brackets, index_sym: integer;
begin
  if s <> '' then 
    if Length(s) = 1 then begin
      New(aTree);
      aTree^.Data := s[1];
      aTree^.Left := nil; aTree^.Right := nil;
    end
    else begin
      brackets := 0;
      index_sym := 1;
      for i := 1 to length(s) do
      begin
        if s[i] = '(' then inc(brackets);
        if s[i] = ')' then dec(brackets);
        if (s[i] <> '(') and (s[i] <> ')') then index_sym := i;
        if (brackets = 0) and (s[i] <> '(') and (s[i] <> ')') then begin
          index_sym := i;
          break;
        end;
      end; 
      AddToTree(aTree, s[index_sym]);
      AddToTree(aTree^.Left, copy(s, 2, index_sym - 3));
      AddToTree(aTree^.Right, copy(s, index_sym + 2, length(s) - 3));
    end;
end;

// Прямой обход бинарного дерева    
procedure PreOrder(aTree: PTree);
begin
  if aTree <> nil then begin
    write(aTree^.Data:4);
    PreOrder(aTree^.Left);
    PreOrder(aTree^.Right);
  end;
end;


var
  t: text;
  s: string;
  BTree: PTree;

begin
  s := '((d)b(((x(y))k)e))a((f(m((h)z)))c(g))';
  BTree := nil;
  AddToTree(BTree, s);
  writeln('Дерево в префиксном порядке :');
  PreOrder(BTree);
end.
```

Comment: Слишком много копирований. Если передавать не строку, а строку и два индекса - можно обойтись вообще без копирований. А если один из индексов передавать ещё и по ссылке - можно избежать отдельного этапа поиска index_sym и сделать всё в один проход (вы просто делаете сначала `AddToTree(aTree^.Left, ...)`, потом там где она остановилась - формируете родительский узел.

Comment: Спасибо за идею, очень полезно